# Using aurelia with a framework (Phoenix)

Tags: webpack, aurelia, phoenix-framework

I have tried aurelia webpack-plugin without results to integrate with Phoenix framework, it would be really nice to have some kind of simple solution or to have pointers besides the sample projects of aurelia webpack plugin to find a solution. I really liked how this new framework and I would like to work with it but without doing a SPA.

Comment: Aurelia is an SPA framework. Support for server-side rendering is in development

Comment: You can just create regular hyperlinks though. If you remove the `#` before the url it will just navigate to another page on your server. You cannot use this with the router, afaik.